# Show subreport footer in main report ACCESS

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a report made of several sub-reports.
These sub-reports have page-header (with titles) and page-footer (with page numbers and specific text) each one.

I can easily get the page-headers for each sub-report setting the property "Show header and footer" to value "Yes". The problem is that only the page-header is repeated on each page for every 'View' configuration, the page-footer are shown only on 'Layout view' but not on 'Print preview'.

I've searched several hours on internet but I couldn't figure out why the page-footers of the sub-reports are not shown in main-report in 'Print preview' neither when I try to export the main-report to pdf.

My main-report and sub-reports does not have any code except for the typically page counter `=[Page]` on the page-footer for the sub-reports.

On the main-report, I am not using the page-header neither the page-footer.

Could anybody tell me how to get the page-footers on each sub-report to be printed?
Is it a Microsoft Access bug? Is there any patch to correct it?
If is not possible to solve it with normal MS-Access tools, is there any workaround?

**Thank you very much in advance**

PS: If there is not any solution, I will be forced to print each sub-report in independent reports and merge them all with an external tool for pdf, but I would like to do it completely with access

**ADITIONAL INFORMATION**

I atthached now a screenshot of the 'Design view' for the main-report where you can see the sub-reports and a censored 'Print preview'. My Access is in spanish. 'Encabezado de página' is 'page-header'. 
[image: censored 'Design view']
[image]

The sub-reports are showing their page-headers but not their page-footers

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question. Are you talking about report-headers/footers (only shown once), or page-headers/footers (shown on every page). Footer are not shown on Layout-View (detail-section has only one page here, so only one footer at the end) or Print-Preview or both? Any code on the report (show)?

Comment: thank you @ComputerVersteher I've modified the question taking into account your remarks

Comment: Sure about the subreports page headers? On access2007 no page header/footer of subreport is printed and I am not surprised because a subreport doesn't know parent reports pages.  But you can use group headers/footers to print specific data before/after a group of details.

Comment: I'm sure of the page headers @ComputerVersteher. I have updated the question to show it to you. I'm not using report headers because they only show the header on the first page (unless I ask them to repeat on each page) and I do not want to use the report footer because, instead of at the end of the link, Print at the end of the last row printed. IN ADDITION to my question. I just discovered that the calculation of the page was done incorrectly :( if I put the page in the header, it will always print page 0: _ (........ I think what I'm trying to do is not possible. ..

Comment: Can confirm on access 2013. Did you tried [grouping](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/page-header-section-of-subreport-not-printing/3144cd0a-9501-4e62-8da7-4c733708255b?page=2)? Pages are count by parent report, but you can refer to them in subreport. If you quit to seperate printing, you can use [ReportToPDF](https://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm) to merge pdfs via vba (on Office x86).